# Debug untouchable UIButton

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, uitouch

I have a really strange problem on my App.
The issue is that:
The `UIButton` inside an `UIView` used as Footer in a UITableView respond correctly to touch only for the half of the height.
No views are over the `UIButton`.

I drawn a red line on the touchable part:

[image]

And this is the Debug View Hierarchy

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a `UITableViewCell`? It looks like the content view's frame isn't as big as the cell's frame. Maybe the bottom constraint of the button is set to the cell's bottom rather than the cell's content view's bottom.

Comment: This is a UIView used as footer in UITableView

Comment: But you catch the problem